# JTextArea not accepting newline keyboard input

Tags: java, swing

Short version: I have a JTextArea widget in a Java 1.8 application that won't accept, on Windows, alt+0010 (newline) or CTRL+J (also newline) as an input.  The return key on the keyboard adds a newline though.  I need it to accept ASCII char 10 from the keyboard and treat it like a newline though.  Calling the `setText()` method with a string like `"This is my newline\ntest case."` does exactly what I'd expect and puts a newline where `\n` appears.

Long version: I'm reading a PDF417 2D barcode in via a USB scanner that sends over text formatted with the newline (0x10) character.  If I use the scanner to read the barcode in with Notepad accepting input the newline character renders properly.  I can get other systems to verify that the newline char is coming across the input but JTextArea just ignores it.

Simplest way to demonstrate it (without uploading a whole skeleton project) is to add a JTextArea to an app, run it, and hit ctrl+J inside the text area to try and add a newline character. Then iterate through the contents of the JTextArea:

```
private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    //jtxtData is a JTextArea object
    String data = jtxtData.getText(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) { 
        System.out.println(data.charAt(i) + ": " + (int)data.charAt(i));
    }
```

Nothing with ASCII 10 will be shown.

Any idea how I can get JTextArea (or any other Swing widget) to accept 0x10 from the keyboard as valid input?

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We obviously don't have access to your USB scanner, so you need a method to create the data that will be appended to the text area.

Comment: Simplest way to demonstrate it (without uploading a whole skeleton project) is to add a JTextArea to an app, run it, and hit ctrl+J inside the text area to try and add a newline character.  Then iterate through the contents of the JTextArea:
<code>
    private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
  //jtxtData is a JTextArea object
  String data = jtxtData.getText();
  for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
   System.out.println(data.charAt(i) + ": " + (int)data.charAt(i));
  }
 </code>

Nothing with ASCII 10 will be shown.

Comment: @JustinBuist it is best to edit your question and put the code there.

Comment: Thanks, @matt.  I've never asked a SO question before.

Comment: `I've never asked a SO question before.` - you were given this suggestion in the very first comment. Did you read the link? `Simplest way to demonstrate it` - we are not here to write test code for you. If you have a problem and have tested it, then post the code you used to test it so we can see exactly what you have done. The code you just posted is NOT an [mcve]. We can not copy/compile and test. We don't have time to write demo code for every question posted.

Comment: `and hit ctrl+J inside the text area` - why do you think CTRL+J should do anything. Maybe the editor of the IDE you use adds a new line, but this is not common functionality. In Swing you use the Enter key to add a newline to the text area.

Comment: @JustinBuist I've edited answer, one way just replaces the windows \r\n with a \n when you grab the text area's text. The other way is to make ctrl +j insert '\n' into your text area. Also, what *is* shown when you use enter to insert your enter?

Comment: @matt using the Enter key results in ASCII code 10 for that character when I pull it back out via `getText()`.

Comment: @JustinBuist So enter works, and your only problem was the ctrl+j or alt character sequence not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So "\n" is equal to 10.

```
    char c = 10;
    String ten = "" + c;
    System.out.println(ten.equals("\n"));
    //true
```

First, since enter works, you could use enter then update your text to have the proper characters.

```
String text = textArea.getText().replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

You can add a key listener for your alt key combo, or ctrl key combo.

```
KeyStroke ctrlj = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('j', InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
Action insertEnter = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textArea.append('\n');
    }
};

textArea.getInputMap().put(ctrlj, "insert enter");
textArea.getActionMap().put("insert enter", insertEnter);
```

It is a bit cumbersome, but that should get ctrl+j to insert enter into your text area.

Comment: There is no need for the replace(...). You can just use `textArea.append(s);` It will recognize the ascii 10. Like you I suggest the data from the USB reader does not contain ascii 10.

Comment: @camickr I was just showing that the character could be replaced if they have a string with a character they cannot print. I also looked at the ascii table and found 10 -> backspace... although that is in octal.

Comment: That doesn't actually get me anywhere.  The getText() method of the JTextArea isn't returning any character when a newline comes from the keyboard.  It's just ignoring it so there's nothing to search and replace on.  Typing alt+0010 or ctrl+j (both newlines) doesn't add a single character to the JTextArea.

Comment: @JustinBuist I thought your issue was the display portion, as in you have some byte[] and you wanted to display it in a text area. You want the other way, to be able to enter the characters into the text area and then read them from the textArea.getText().

Comment: Yes, Key Bindings is the way to bind a KeyStroke to an Action. But I would suggest you don't need to create a new Action, just use the existing Action provided by the editor kit. The link in my answer shows how this can be done.

Comment: @camickr I was under the impression the existing action didn't work. As in <enter> wasn't providing the correct results.

Comment: The OP states: `The return key on the keyboard adds a newline though.`.

Comment: @carmickr yes, as in a visible line in the text area. But it sounded like it wasn't adding just a '\n' as in it wasn't working some way. Which could be a "\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

> hit ctrl+J inside the text area to try and add a newline character

CTRL+J is nothing special to Swing. Not sure why you think it should add a newline. The Enter key is used to add a newline in Swing.

Swing uses `Key Bindings` to add `Action`s to `KeyStroke`s. In Swing the Enter key is mapped to an Action to add an newline character into the Document. Check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for the list of default bindings.

If you want you can add Ctrl+J as another KeyStroke to add a newline character. The link shows how you can add another binding by either:

1. sharing an Action with a different KeyStroke
2. binding an Action name to a KeyStroke

Although I still don't understand how this will help solve your problem, since you stated the data is coming from a USB reader and formatted before being passed to the text area. This is why we need proper code that demonstrates the problem.